# How to download a media file using Gramjs and Telegram API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, telegram

The next code is taken from the documentation (https://gram.js.org/tl/upload/GetFile#uploadgetfile):

```
const data = await client.invoke(
  new Api.upload.GetFile({
    location: new Api.InputFileLocation({
      volumeId: BigInt("-4156887774564"),
      localId: 43,
      secret: BigInt("-4156887774564"),
      fileReference: Buffer.from("arbitrary data here"),
    }),
    offset: BigInt("-4156887774564"),
    limit: 100,
    precise: true,
    cdnSupported: true,
  })
);
```

I would like to ask a few questions.

1. There is a problem with the parameters `volumeId`, `secret` and `offset`. When hovering the cursor, a pop-up hint appears "Type 'bigint' is not assignable to type 'BigInteger'.ts(2322)". How to transform these values to the type that is required? In the documentation, I did not find mention of this.
2. The second question is - what should be in the parameters `volumeId`, `localId`, `secret`, `fileReference`, `offset` and `limit`?

I already have a `JSON` of chat history taken by `Messages.gethistory`. I will give below the fragment of the `JSON`, - the parameter `media` of the last message:

```
"media": {
  "flags": 1,
  "nopremium": false,
  "spoiler": false,
  "document": {
    "flags": 1,
    "id": "5381878726680130068",
    "accessHash": "-5928175209338587382",
    "fileReference": {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [2, 82, 208, etc...]
    },
    "date": 1691769537,
    "mimeType": "video/mp4",
    "size": "63998085",
    "thumbs": [
      {
        "type": "i",
        "bytes": {
          "type": "Buffer",
          "data": [1, 22, 40, etc...]
        },
        "className": "PhotoStrippedSize"
      },
      {
        "type": "m",
        "w": 320,
        "h": 180,
        "size": 8499,
        "className": "PhotoSize"
      }
    ],
    "videoThumbs": null,
    "dcId": 2,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "flags": 2,
        "roundMessage": false,
        "supportsStreaming": true,
        "nosound": false,
        "duration": 169.26666666667,
        "w": 848,
        "h": 464,
        "preloadPrefixSize": null,
        "className": "DocumentAttributeVideo"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "IMG_2341.MP4",
        "className": "DocumentAttributeFilename"
      }
    ],
    "className": "Document"
  },
  "altDocument": null,
  "ttlSeconds": null,
  "className": "MessageMediaDocument"
}
```

Can you suggest what exactly needs to be set into the above code in the parameters that I have listed?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck on this these days but I just figured it out how to make it work.

Follow my working code:

```
                const buffer = await client.downloadFile(
                    new Api.InputPhotoFileLocation({
                        id: photo.id,
                        accessHash: photo.accessHash,
                        fileReference: photo.fileReference,
                        thumbSize: "y"
                    }),
                    {
                        dcId: photo.dcId,
                        //fileSize: "y",
                    }
                );

                fs.writeFileSync('output.jpg', buffer);
```

If it doesn't work, try adapting to your case.

Comment: reference: https://gram.js.org/beta/classes/TelegramClient.html#downloadFile